# Where to place the assets folder in AIDE?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-assets, aide-ide, android-ide

I'm using [AIDE](http://www.android-ide.com/) (A code editor / IDE & compiler which runs on Android) to write an Android app, and I want to add some assets to my project, specifically a HTML file plus associated CSS and JavaScript files, to be displayed in a WebView.

I've put my assets (a HTML file) in `projectDirectory/app/src/main/assets/htmlfile.html`, but,  when I use the code below to load it in WebView, it shows "File not found". The exact same thing works fine in Android Studio.

**Where do I put this assets folder for AIDE to pick up its contents ?**

---

Here is my code where I'm loading the WebView, although I don't think there's anything wrong here, as it works in Android Studio.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    WebView webView = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webView);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/htmlfile.html");
}
```

What I've tried:

- Placing it in `/app/src/main/assets/htmlfile.html` (The usual location, which works in Android Studio).
- In `/app/src/main/res/assets/htmlfile.html`
- In `/app/src/assets/htmlfile.html`
- Pretty much everywhere else.

However, wherever I put it and recompile, the WebView always shows "File not found". So where do I put my assets folder for it to work with AIDE, or how do I make AIDE pick it up when compiling ? Does AIDE support assets at all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh: All I needed to do was **menu** > **more** > **project** > **refresh build**, with the assets in `/app/src/main/assets/htmlfile.html` and it worked. Somewhat non-obvious, but hey, solved my problem.

Leaving this self answer in case anyone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

As for an html keep it in **app->src->main->assets**

And later on you can acces it like **"file:///android_asset/error.html"**

Lets take example of a webview wv1. You can write

```
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
```

Dont forget to rebuild your project. This is a safety measure in such case. Many times files are not included automatically

Comment: Thanks, I was already doing all this and using the webview in this way, but the rebuilding the project did the trick and made it actually work, as I described in my own answer. Thanks though  !